# Upload file from Android application to Pirated Box

Tags: android, python

Hello Developer,
           I have configured **Pirated Box** in some server. 
The link for details regarding pirated box is as follows 
[Pirated Box Android](http://fun2code-blog.blogspot.in/2011/12/piratebox-on-android.html)

In pirated box there is **Droopy** Control which is used to upload file.
You can see Droopy details in following link:
[Droopy Details](http://www.techkings.org/general-pc-chat/34104-droopy-tutorial.html)

I am able to upload the file using droopy to specific folder in pirated box.
Now I want to upload the file from android application to pirated box. Anyone having idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering to my own question. This is the code which helped me to achieve the task

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri)
    {
        int serverResponseCode =0;
        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile())
        {
            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL("http://piratebox.lan:8080/");

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upfile\"; filename=" + fileName + "" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/png" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data neccesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if (serverResponseCode == 200)
                {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            String msg = "File Upload Completed";
                        }
                    });
                }
                //close the streams
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block
    }
```